# Double representation differences

Tags: c#, .net-core, floating-point

We have two projects running on .NET Core 3.1.420. One project is a copy of the other, with some changes to its UI/backend logic.

Both projects have the following class, with the exact same values.

```
public class DebuggerOptions
{
    public double Double1 => 0.08;
    public double Double2 => 0.015;
    public double Double3 => 0.05;
}
```

When we inspect the *DebuggerOptions* instance in the "old" project. We're seeing the correct representation of the doubles.
In the "new" project we're seeing values like

- Double1 = 0.080000000000000002
- Double2 = 0.014999999999999999
- Double3 = 0.050000000000000003

I'm personnaly seeing these differences on two machines running Windows 11. My colleague tried running both projects on his machine running Windows 10 and he is seeing the correct (exact) representation.

We're doing some precise calculations and these doubles are inputs which cause the result to be way off.

Has something changed to the IEEE 754 implementation in Windows 11? Are we missing some configuration? We're kind of lost at this point. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think its more likely the debugger (or whatever your colleague is seeing) is not showing the exact value - that's my guess (seems backed up by testing here: https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/

Comment: You can't store a value like 0.05 exactly as `double`. Only fractions with powers of two like 1/32 can (or multiples thereof). Use `decimal` instead if the decimals matter.

Comment: `0.08` can't be represented exactly in a `double`, so `0.080000000000000002` is actually closer to the correct value. The difference you're seeing is only due to the output precision of the string representation, not the actual IEEE representation.

Comment: [Try this online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uDqb1g) and look at the different values depending on the number of decimal places specified in the ToString()

Comment: Thanks for the information. We understand that these values can't be stored exactly. But how does one explain why Visual Studio is representing the values "correctly" one time and the other "incorrectly"?

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain the differences. But from a developing/programming point of view you should *always* assume that floating point values with decimal parts are inexact representations of the numbers they are meant to contain and may not be the same as what the look like - unless you have gone to special pains to determine otherwise. And of course never use floating point datatypes when you need exactness in decimal parts. Eighteen decimal places out is very close to the exact number of course, and sometimes satisfactory, but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm personally seeing these differences on two machines running Windows 11. My colleague tried running both projects on his machine running Windows 10 and he is seeing the correct (exact) representation.

You have not posted how you are personally seeing these differences.  Instead, post code that reports the values.

Your colleague's approach is also not posted.  Colleague's approach is *not* seeing the *exact* values.

`double` can store about 2<sup>64</sup> different values<sup>*1</sup> *exactly*.  `0.08, 0.015, 0.05` are *not* in that set - instead nearby values are used.  The different values you are seeing are due to the different ways of examining that data.  Instead, report values with code in floating point hexadecimal notation, or print exponentially with at least 17 *significant* decimal digits.

---

<sup>*1</sup> All such values are some integer times a power-of-two.
See [Dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).

Comment: I'm sorry, we are using Visual Studio to break in the constructor of the application. And at that point we are seeing different representations. Which we find really weird.

Comment: @StephanBisschop Rather than only describe the values as different, post those _different values_ and the way they were found.

Comment: My original post already contained the different values. I added how they were found.

Comment: @StephanBisschop Where is the addition that shows how they were found?  Are both you and your colleague  reading the values with the same precision?  As answered here, with decimal, unless you are reporting values at least 17 digits of _significant_ precision, you (and likely your colleague) are only reporting heavily rounded values and not a  true enough one.